# How to transform SoapFault to SoapMessage via Interceptor in CXF?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I have web-service created and configured via `Spring` and `CXF`. See beans below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans <!-- ommited -->>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <bean id="internalActService" class="package.InternalActServiceImpl" />

    <jaxws:endpoint implementor="#internalActService" address="/InternalActService">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
        </jaxws:properties>

        <jaxws:outFaultInterceptors>
            <bean class="package.InternalActServiceFaultOutInterceptor" />
        </jaxws:outFaultInterceptors>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

As can you see I added schema validation to my web service. But `CXF` throws `SoapFault` when request is not corresponding with schema.
I want to send to the client `SoapMessage` instead of `SoapFault`, that's why I added `outFaultInterceptors`.

My question is how to transform `SoapFaul`t to `SoapMessage`? I've made few tries but I don't know how to implement `outFaultInterceptor`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably you forgot to setup interceptor phase and its order in the interceptor chain.

Try something like this:

```
package org.foo.bar;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class InternalActServiceFaultOutInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public InternalActServiceFaultOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
        addBefore(Arrays.asList(StaxOutInterceptor.class.getName(), AttachmentOutInterceptor.class.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        Exception exception = message.getContent(Exception.class);
        if(exception != null) {
            message.getExchange().put(Exception.class, null);

            for(Class<?> contentFormat : message.getContentFormats()) {
                message.setContent(contentFormat, null);
            }

            message.setContent(List.class, new MessageContentsList(createSoapMessage(RegisterDocumentResponse.class)));
        }
    }

    protected <T> T createSoapMessage(Class<T> messageType) {
        // create your message
        return null;
    }

}
```

---

-EDIT-

Here is a unit test that works for me. It's a little bit tricky to be able to send POJOs to the output. I suppose it can be much more simpler if constructing DOM by yourself.

### Interceptor

```
package foo.bar;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Interceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.InterceptorChain;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.apache.cxf.service.model.BindingMessageInfo;
import org.apache.cxf.service.model.BindingOperationInfo;
import org.apache.cxf.service.model.MessageInfo;
import org.apache.cxf.service.model.OperationInfo;
import org.apache.cxf.service.model.ServiceModelUtil;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyOutInterceptor;

public class InternalActServiceFaultOutInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public InternalActServiceFaultOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.SETUP);
        addBefore(Arrays.asList(PolicyOutInterceptor.class.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        Exchange exchange = message.getExchange();

        resetOrigInterceptorChain(message);
        resetFault(exchange);

        Message outMessage = createOutMessage(exchange);

        InterceptorChain chain = prepareNewInterceptorChain(exchange);
        chain.doIntercept(outMessage);
    }

    private InterceptorChain prepareNewInterceptorChain(Exchange exchange) {
        Message message = exchange.getOutMessage();
        bind(message);

        InterceptorChain chain = OutgoingChainInterceptor.getOutInterceptorChain(exchange);
        message.setInterceptorChain(chain);

        return chain;
    }

    private Message createOutMessage(Exchange exchange) {
        Endpoint ep = exchange.get(Endpoint.class);

        Message outMessage = ep.getBinding().createMessage();
        outMessage.setExchange(exchange);
        outMessage.setContent(List.class, new MessageContentsList(createSoapMessage()));

        exchange.setOutMessage(outMessage);
        return outMessage;
    }

    private void resetFault(Exchange exchange) {
        exchange.put(Exception.class, null);
    }

    private void resetOrigInterceptorChain(SoapMessage message) {
        InterceptorChain chain = message.getInterceptorChain();
        for(Interceptor<?> interceptor : chain) {
            chain.remove(interceptor);
        }
        chain.reset();
    }

    private void bind(Message message) {
        Exchange exchange = message.getExchange();
        BindingOperationInfo bop = unwrap(message.getExchange().getBindingOperationInfo());

        message.put(MessageInfo.class, bop.getOperationInfo().getOutput());
        message.put(BindingMessageInfo.class, bop.getOutput());

        bop = unwrap(ServiceModelUtil.getOperationForWrapperElement(exchange, bop.getName(), false));

        exchange.put(BindingOperationInfo.class, bop);
        if (bop != null) {
            exchange.put(BindingOperationInfo.class, bop);
            exchange.put(OperationInfo.class, bop.getOperationInfo());
        }
    }

    private BindingOperationInfo unwrap(BindingOperationInfo bop) {
        while(bop.getUnwrappedOperation() != null) {
            bop = bop.getUnwrappedOperation();
            return bop;
        }
        return bop;
    }

    protected Echo createSoapMessage() {
        Echo e = new Echo();
        e.setValue("Bye World!");
        return e;
    }

}
```

### Request/Response POJO

```
package foo.bar;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "EchoType")
public class Echo {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

### WebService

```
package foo.bar;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class InternalActServiceImpl {
    public Echo echo(Echo val) {
        return val;
    }
}
```

### Spring Context: CxfInterceptorTest-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http-jetty.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxws.xml" />

    <bean id="internalActService" class="foo.bar.InternalActServiceImpl" />

    <jaxws:endpoint implementor="#internalActService" address="http://localhost:9080/InternalActService">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
        </jaxws:properties>
        <jaxws:outFaultInterceptors>
            <bean class="foo.bar.InternalActServiceFaultOutInterceptor" />
        </jaxws:outFaultInterceptors>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

### Unit Test

```
package foo.bar;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class CxfInterceptorTest {

    private static final String REQ =
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:bar=\"http://bar.foo/\">\r\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Header/>\r\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Body>\r\n" +
            "      <bar:echo>\r\n" +
            "         <arg0>\r\n" +
            "            <value1>Hello World</value1>\r\n" +
            "         </arg0>\r\n" +
            "      </bar:echo>\r\n" +
            "   </soapenv:Body>\r\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    @Test
    public void validate() throws Exception {
        String s = call();
        Assert.assertTrue(s.contains("Bye World!"));
    }

    private String call() throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9080/InternalActService");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "");

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(REQ.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        final int buffSize = 1024;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(buffSize);
        for(int readBytes = -1; (readBytes = is.read(buff, 0, buffSize)) != -1; ) {
            builder.append(new String(buff, 0, readBytes));
        }

        is.close();

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have slight issue with the code, all I want is to reset fault and and a new soap message to it but I also need to add ws-addressing to at some point and this isn't doint it for me, any suggestions? p.s. I am doing all this in Mule ESB.

Answer (score 2):

Your interceptor should implement

[org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/Interceptor.html)

The handleFault of handleMessage method will be called. The parameter is both cases will be an instance of

[org.apache.cxf.message.Message](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Message.html)

You can call on that

```
removeContent()
```

or

```
setContent()
```

to replace the message.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking for more specific answer. My `InternalActServiceFaultOutInterceptor` extends `AbstractSoapInterceptor`. In `handleMessage` method I'm trying to switch response by removing exception:
`soapMessage.removeContent(java.lang.Exception.class)` and setting different content by `soapMessage.setContent(RegisterDocumentResponse.class, content);`. Despite that the fact `soapMessage.getContentFormats()`shows `[class package.RegisterDocumentResponse, class java.io.OutputStream, interface javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter]` the web-service client still sees `<soap:Fault>`.

Comment: probably you should double check if you removed everything from the Message, there might be something left there. If that doesnt work you can always fall back to the brute force solution and add a servlet filter that does the job, not nice, but would work...

Comment: Im not sure if it's always working:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984617/propagate-exception-from-cxf-interceptor-to-exception-mapper